# Order of reducer and saga

Tags: redux-saga

When dispatching an action is the order when it arrives to a reducer and a saga guaranteed?

Can I rely on that it

1. first enters the reducer
2. then the saga?

Reducer:

```
 function reducer(state, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
       case 'MY_ACTION':
       // decorate action so that an epic doesn't have to take data from store
       action.ports = state.itemsModified;                 
       return state;
     }
    }
```

Saga:

```
export function* sagaUpdatePorts() {
    yield* ReduxSaga.takeEvery(actions.GRID_PORTS_ASYNC_UPDATE_PORTS, updatePorts);
}

function* updatePorts(action) {
    const {response, error} = yield SagaEffects.call(portsService.updatePorts, action.ports);
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes. The action hits the reducer first then Sagas.

This is [mentioned in the docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#selectselector-args) under the `select()` effect API:

> It's important to note that when an action is dispatched to the store, the middleware first forwards the action to the reducers and then notifies the Sagas. This means that when you query the Store's State, you get the State **after** the action has been applied. However, this behavior is only guaranteed if all subsequent middlewares call `next(action)` synchronously. If any subsequent middleware calls `next(action)` asynchronously (which is unusual but possible), then the sagas will get the state from **before** the action is applied. Therefore it is recommended to review the source of each subsequent middleware to ensure it calls `next(action)` synchronously, or else ensure that redux-saga is the last middleware in the call chain.

Comment: Thx, Yassine. One more thing before accepting the answer. Can you provide a link to the docs if it's there? Or is your answer based on your sole opinion?

Comment: I wrote the library so maybe this would give some guarantee ☺

Comment: Gotta trust you, Bro. ;) Accepted

Comment: @YassineElouafi as per your comment was that added to the documentation?

Comment: @Kamaraju https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#selectselector-args

Comment: Here are the lines in code so you can see for yourself :) https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/4348497e1c22bb5656c1905af19e25f8e7d29c61/packages/core/src/internal/middleware.js#L27-L28

Comment: I wonder what is the reasoning behind the design decision to run saga after reducers. "Middleware" name implies something to happen before it reaches the reducers)